# Dependency injection of IStringLocalizer in Application project when Clean Architecture application is used

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In a Clean Architecture, I have 4 projects in .NET 6.0:

- Web API
- Application
- Domain
- Infrastructure

References between projects :

- API project reference `Application` project
- Application project reference `Domain` and `Infrastructure` projects
- Domain as no reference
- Infrastructure project reference `Domain` project

In the controller `MyController`, I use `IStringLocalizer` to return text based base on the `CurrentThread Culture`, that's work when I do this  `_localizer["Article"]` no problem.

In the controller :

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<MyController> _localizer;
    
    public MyController(IMyService myService, IStringLocalizer<MyController> localizer)
    {
        _myService = myService;
        _localizer = localizer;
    }
    
    public IActionResult Search(Parameter Dto)
    {
        var val = _localizer["Article"];
    
        var response = _myService.Search(parameter);
    
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

But I'd like to use `IStringLocalizer` in the `Application` project but it's not possible to do via DI because `MyController` is unknow and with this architecture `API` project can't be add as reference (and not possible because circular reference error)

In the Application project :

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    public MyService(IStringLocalizer<MyController> myController)
    {
    }
}
```

How can I solve it ?

Thanks,

Update 1 :
That's partially work, the resources files are in `API` project, I do this in `startup.cs` :

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddViewLocalization
        (LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
    var supportedCultures = new[] { "fr-BE", "nl-BE", "en-US" };
    options.SetDefaultCulture(supportedCultures[0])
        .AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures);
});
```

In the resource file, I have for `"Article"` in `MyController.fr-BE : "Article FR"` and in `MyController.nl-BE : "Article NL". The ResourcesPath is probably not correct but how set` ResourcesPath`to`API`or move to`Application` project

Comment: Shouldn't you anyway be using `IStringLocalizer<MyService>` inside the service class, since the `IStringLocalizer` would be providing strings to `MyService` and not necessarily to `MyController` since any class could use `MyService`

Comment: @MindSwipe it's better, the first step is ok, now need to get the text from the resource files. See update 1

Answer (score 0):

The path is ok,but you have to create a floder in your Application project name of "Resources" and add the resourece files for the classes in Application proj like:

[image]

I tried as below:

```
namespace Application
{
    public interface ISomeService 
    {
        string SomeMethod();
    }
    public class SomeService: ISomeService
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> _localizer;
        public SomeService(IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> localizer)
        {
            _localizer = localizer;
        }
        public string SomeMethod()
        {
            return _localizer["HI"].Value;
        }
    }    
}
```

Get the localized value successfully:

[image]